# Dynamically remove rows from a datasource/database in gridview delete button handler

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms, sqldatasource

I have many different data sources being linked to different tables. One for each table. I have the edit and delete buttons showing on my gridview and have the subsequent methods created in my code, however no meat in the methods.

I am focusing on the delete portion of this for now. I am not sure what to do to reference the data source currently assigned so I can execute a delete on the table.

The data sources were all created using the auto creation wizard where I told it to auto generate the insert delete and update statement.

The relevant code:

```
<asp:GridView   ID="GridView1" runat="server"  
                AutoGenerateEditButton="true" AutoGenerateDeleteButton="true" AllowPaging="true" 
                OnRowEditing="GridView1_RowEditing" 
                OnRowDeleting="GridView1_RowDeleting" 
                OnRowCancelingEdit="GridView1_RowCancelingEdit" 
                OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating" 
                style="position:absolute; left:10%; width:80%; margin:0; top: 140px; height: 353px;" >
</asp:GridView>


<asp:SqlDataSource  ID="StoresDataSource" runat="server" 
                    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:crudConnectionString %>" 
                    DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [Stores] WHERE [StoreID] = @StoreID" 
                    InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [Stores] ([Location], [StoreTypeID], [StoreTrafficTypeID], [MarketID], [TmoSAP], [SubDealerID], [Default Traffic], [DateOpen], [DateClosed], [StorePhone], [StoreFax], [StoreAddress], [StoreCity], [StoreState], [StoreZip], [County], [StoreEmail], [QuickBooksRef], [AccountingClass], [TMOMarket], [KeyFOBLocation], [InstallerID], [AccessDBStoreID], [DateModified], [ModifiedBy], [Layout], [Class], [Contract_ID]) VALUES (@Location, @StoreTypeID, @StoreTrafficTypeID, @MarketID, @TmoSAP, @SubDealerID, @Default_Traffic, @DateOpen, @DateClosed, @StorePhone, @StoreFax, @StoreAddress, @StoreCity, @StoreState, @StoreZip, @County, @StoreEmail, @QuickBooksRef, @AccountingClass, @TMOMarket, @KeyFOBLocation, @InstallerID, @AccessDBStoreID, @DateModified, @ModifiedBy, @Layout, @Class, @Contract_ID)" 
                    SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [Stores]" 
                    UpdateCommand="UPDATE [Stores] SET [Location] = @Location, [StoreTypeID] = @StoreTypeID, [StoreTrafficTypeID] = @StoreTrafficTypeID, [MarketID] = @MarketID, [TmoSAP] = @TmoSAP, [SubDealerID] = @SubDealerID, [Default Traffic] = @Default_Traffic, [DateOpen] = @DateOpen, [DateClosed] = @DateClosed, [StorePhone] = @StorePhone, [StoreFax] = @StoreFax, [StoreAddress] = @StoreAddress, [StoreCity] = @StoreCity, [StoreState] = @StoreState, [StoreZip] = @StoreZip, [County] = @County, [StoreEmail] = @StoreEmail, [QuickBooksRef] = @QuickBooksRef, [AccountingClass] = @AccountingClass, [TMOMarket] = @TMOMarket, [KeyFOBLocation] = @KeyFOBLocation, [InstallerID] = @InstallerID, [AccessDBStoreID] = @AccessDBStoreID, [DateModified] = @DateModified, [ModifiedBy] = @ModifiedBy, [Layout] = @Layout, [Class] = @Class, [Contract_ID] = @Contract_ID WHERE [StoreID] = @StoreID">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{

}

protected void GridView1_RowDeleted(object sender, GridViewDeletedEventArgs e)
{            
    //DataBind();            
}
```

Comment: I do not know how to delete rows from `SqlDataSource` manually, but if you already use it, then why don't you just set `DataSourceID` in `GridView` to allow automatic removal and editing - http://www.asp.net/web-forms/overview/data-access/accessing-the-database-directly-from-an-aspnet-page/inserting-updating-and-deleting-data-with-the-sqldatasource-cs?

Comment: I tried to figure out how to do it but i couldnt figure out how to get it to do it without binding the table to the gridview. wasnt sure if that was the way i wanted to go.

Comment: You will probably be able to do it manually with [SqlDataSource.Delete](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.sqldatasource.delete(v=vs.110).aspx) method, but with GridView and SqlDataSource connected through `DataSourceID` property you will have far less hassle in any mundane case.

Comment: Can you give me some idea how to hook the grid view up with the datasourceid?

Comment: I have given you a link to a comprehensive tutorial in the first comment.

Comment: And my big question, after i bind the table to the grid view, can i unbind it and bind it to my next table? I have 40 tables and dont want to have to create 40 gridviews if possible. I have been using a drop down to select a list item and that in turn decides what sqldatasource to use for the gridview

Comment: That is a bit different problem, so you will probably be better starting another question thread. Just make sure that you research the problem thoroughly on your own before asking - I am confident that there exist some info on dynamic GridView data binding.

Comment: Thanks, i will look more into it